# Does caching mean it might be useful to split a query into two parts?

Tags: database, performance, caching

If I want to return a frequently used list which contains a small amount of personalised data, is it worth splitting into two queries?

Let's say I have two lists: allBooks, and myReadBooks

allBooks is shared by everyone using the app, and is a heavily cached. myReadBooks is the list of books read by the user.

Instead of doing a monster personalised query on allBooks that never hits the cache, I could query the cached value for allBooks, and then "hydrate" that with the data from a separate query to myReadBooks. The tradeoff is maintainability and complexity of hydration, as well as the extra query to a server.

Is this multi-query approach used regularly in production or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: in general databases do caching behind the scenes. until you have an actual problem don't worry about it.